# How do you convert float to a decimal integer times a power of 2?

Tags: floating-point

For example taking 3.5625 and representing it as such -> 57 * 2^-4. If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Using what language?

Comment: Are you looking for a string representation?  The internal representation of C type float is similar to what you described, although the integer is binary.  More clarity, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general method (maybe there is a more clever or mathematical way):

Multiply by 2 repeatedly until it has no more decimal component. Take the resulting number and multiply by 2^-n where n is the number of iterations it took to get there.

Your example:

```
3.5625
3.5625 * 2              =  7.125
3.5625 * 2 * 2          = 14.25
3.5625 * 2 * 2 * 2      = 28.5
3.5625 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2  = 57
```

So it took 4 iterations, therefore:

```
57 * 2^-4
```